# Google Colap Failed to load response from ChatGPT extension

Tags: google-colaboratory, chatgpt-plugin

Failed to load response from ChatGPT:
{"detail":"Only one message at a time. Please allow any other responses to complete before sending another message, or wait one minute."}

Failed to load response from ChatGPT and expecting Quick Solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask